# Most stable version of Spring 4.x?

Tags: spring

I want to upgrade my application from spring 3.x version to Spring 4.x version, and I would like to know which one is the most stable(no bugs).. thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use 4.2.1.RELEASE (as of now). See http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/ for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to visit [mvnrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com)

I always took a version with suffix **'RELEASE'**
Please remember to migrate all your 3.x spring dependencies.If you will forgot to do this - you can get **NoSuchMethodError**
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context/4.2.1.RELEASE